# Add a "Next" Button/Link to Crud Edit/Create view

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm trying to add a next button to the Edit/Create view that will take users to the next tab.

Would like the button to be at the bottom like so:

[Next Link is meant to take user to the next tab (tab 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npExT.png)

[clicking link remains on tab 1 instead of moving to tab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtWhg.png)

Tried adding HTML field with the link to the next tab like so:

```html
[   // CustomHTML Title
  'name' => 'next_part_2',
  'type' => 'custom_html',
  'value' => '<a href="#" onclick="<a href="#tab_part2" aria-controls="tab_part2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Part 2</a>">Next Page</a>',
  'tab' => 'Part 1'
],
```

Expect this to open the next tab (i.e. tab 2), but no luck

No JS errors - the link disappears and tab remains on the current view.

Any ideas how to achieve next button on the Edit/Create views?

The a HTML element was taken directly from the tab link with the assumption that it would work. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Found this code snippet that helped come up with a solution: https://www.bootply.com/112163

In my case, I did the following:

1. Created a helper function:

   function nextTab( nextID ){
       $('a[href="' + nextID +'"]').tab('show');
   }
2. Create HTML field with a link and onclick method:

   [   // CustomHTML Title
     'name' => 'next_part_2',
      'type' => 'custom_html',
      'value' => 'Continue to part 2 →',
      'tab' => 'Part 1'
   ],